# Types defined in a package object aren't in scope

Tags: scala

To avoid writing out a large type in several places in my code, I thought I'd shortcut it using a type declaration in a package object:

```
package pet

package object pet {
    type Ops = ((Int,Int) => Int,String)
}

object Q extends App {
    val ops = List[Ops](
        ((_+_),"+"),
        ((_-_),"-"),
        ((_*_),"*")
    )
}
```

But it's saying that for `val ops`, `Ops` isn't found. I'm guessing I'm misunderstanding something, but after looking over several package object examples, I can't tell what. There are no errors in the package object itself, so I don't think that it's a problem with that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When declaring a `package object`, you need to place it in the package "above". As it stands, you're declaring `package object pet` *inside* `package pet`, so that `Ops` is actually located at the path `pet.pet.Ops`.

In your case, you should just place the `package object` inside it's own file without any `package` declaration.

If you were to `import pet.pet._` inside `Q` it would also work.

Comment: or have `package object pet { ... }` followed by `package pet { }` if you really want to stick with one file.

Comment: Thank you. I probably won't need it in any other files, so I'll just do the internal import. If I did put it in another file though, without a package declaration, how would it know that that package object is in scope of the intended package? Does it look for matching names?

Comment: @Carcigenicate Without a package declaration it sits in the root path. But say you have `package com.example.test`, and you want a `package object test`, you would place it in `package com.example`. [For example](https://github.com/mhzajac/anorm-relational/blob/master/src/main/scala/com/jaroop/anorm/relational/relational.scala)

Comment: @m-z Ah, thank you. I'm not using nested packages, so I can't do that. I ended up having to put it in a separate file because the type I'm shortcutting is in a class's constructor. Eclipse labelled the package as "Default package", and everything compiles, so that should be it. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 0):

> Each package is allowed to have one package object. Any definitions
>   placed in a package object are considered members of the package
>   itself.

As seen from [here](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/packageobjects/packageobjects.html), the definitions are package specific (in this case `pet.pet`). So you need to `import` them for use.

You can try:

```
object Q extends App {
  import pet.pet._
  ...
```